# Etiqueta <em> se crea sola en código html

Tags: html, css

mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo dos bloques div creados dinamicamente (php y mysql) y de un tiempo para acá en el 2do bloque div se crea de manera automática una etiqueta em
esto provoca que se altere el posicionamiento css y ya no salgan los bloques div uno al lado del otro. Cabe decir que el código no se ha tocado desde hace tiempo, por lo que debería seguir funcionando correctamente. He googleado y no he dado con una solucion. Alquien sabe a que se debe esto? gracias de antemano.

esta seccion me crea los bloques

```
<?php   
  $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM nacs ORDER BY pk_nacs DESC  limit 2")
                                  or die('error: '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
  while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
    echo " 

      <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='h-100 p-5 bg-light rounded shadow'>
          <h3 class='text-vine fw-bold'>$data[tit]</h3>
          <div class='d-flex bd-highlight'>
            <p>Fecha: $nFecha </p>   
            <div class='flex-grow-1' style='padding: 0.8rem 1rem 0 0.5rem!important;height: 10px;'>
              <div style='width: 100%; border-bottom: 3px solid #7F273F;'></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class=''>$s_final...</p>
          <a href='nacs.php?index=$data[pk_nacs]' class='btn btn-outline-secondary'>Ver más noticias nacionales...</a>
        </div>
      </div>
";
      }
?>
```

luego el resultado es algo como esto

```
<div class="row align-items-md-stretch">

 

      <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='h-100 p-5 bg-light rounded shadow'>
          <h3 class='text-vine fw-bold'>Científicos venezolanos producirán con biotecnología musáceas tolerantes a enfermedades</h3>
          <div class='d-flex bd-highlight'>
            <p>Fecha: 27/02/2021 </p>   
            <div class='flex-grow-1' style='padding: 0.8rem 1rem 0 0.5rem!important;height: 10px;'>
              <div style='width: 100%; border-bottom: 3px solid #7F273F;'></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class=''>...</p>
          <a href='nacs.php?index=149' class='btn btn-outline-secondary'>Ver más noticias nacionales...</a>
        </div>
      </div>
 
     <em>
      <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='h-100 p-5 bg-light rounded shadow'>
          <h3 class='text-vine fw-bold'>Recomiendan a la población vacunada contra la COVID-19 mantener uso del tapaboca</h3>
          <div class='d-flex bd-highlight'>
            <p>Fecha: 26/02/2021 </p>   
            <div class='flex-grow-1' style='padding: 0.8rem 1rem 0 0.5rem!important;height: 10px;'>
              <div style='width: 100%; border-bottom: 3px solid #7F273F;'></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p class=''>...</p>
          <a href='nacs.php?index=148' class='btn btn-outline-secondary'>Ver más noticias nacionales...</a>
        </div>
      </div>
     </em>
    <em>.........</em>
    </div>
```

aun dato adicional, eso ocurre en el servidor web, si lo pruebo en local funciona perfectamente

Comment: Por favor agrega el código.

Comment: Adjunta un [repro] de tu problema en cuestión. Lee [ask].

Comment: @DavElsanto listo ya coloqué el código

Comment: He replicado tu código con una tabla de prueba y no me genera error alguno ni etiquetas `<em>`. No se que mas decirte...

Comment: @OCHOA gracias por tomarte el tiempo. Si, es que yo tampoco le encuentro sentido. Porque en caso tal, debería generar las etiquetas em en los dos bloques div generados dinámicamente no en uno solo.

Answer (score 0):

He ejecutado tu código cambiando el valor de las variables por "aa" y el resultado no me ha dado ningún `<em>`.

```
$data="aa";
         echo "<div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='h-100 p-5 bg-light rounded shadow'>
      <h3 class='text-vine fw-bold'>$data</h3>
      <div class='d-flex bd-highlight'>
        <p>Fecha: $data </p>   
        <div class='flex-grow-1' style='padding: 0.8rem 1rem 0 0.5rem!important;height: 10px;'>
          <div style='width: 100%; border-bottom: 3px solid #7F273F;'></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class=''>$data...</p>
      <a href='nacs.php?index=$data' class='btn btn-outline-secondary'>Ver más noticias nacionales...</a>
    </div>
  </div>";
```

[image: resultado]

Te diría que revises el contenido de las variables no tengan ni comillas o caracteres raros.

Comment: Esto parece más bien un comentario, no una respuesta. Lee [answer]. Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges) podrás dejar comentarios.

Comment: Uhmmm ok muchas gracias @dixlesicoperdido lo tomaré en cuenta. Tal vez al titulo o al contenido de la nota de prensa le hayan colocado comillas, porque se trata de un gestor de noticias.

Comment: Cuando veas que una pregunta no se puede reproducir, indicaselo al autor y reportala.

Comment: Buenas noches, estimados...., @dixlesicoperdido, le comento que en cierto modo di con el problema, gracias a su comentario. Trata de una librería ckeditor.js. Ella guarda en el campo de la bd las etiquetas del estilo HTML junto con el texto normal que agrega el usuario y cuando se coloca un texto en negritas hace que genere esas em que encierran el bloque. Ahí está el error. El detalle es que no se ni por qué hace eso ni como solventarlo.